# Dynamically load different UserControls based on object type via data binding in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

Is there some way in WPF to get the same functionality `DataTemplateSelector` gives you, but for UserControls?

Say I have a StackView to which I want to bind an IEnumerable of objects.  What I'd like to do is somehow have a mapping that, for each object type in the bound IEnumerable, looks at the object type and determines what UserControl to add to the StackView.

So, given three classes:

```
public class House : Building{}

public class Apartment : Building{}

public class Tent : Building{}
```

where each class inherits from `Building` and has its own defined `UserControl`, I'd like to set `DataContext` to an `IEnumerable<Building>` and somehow get the StackView to populate its set of children with the type-specific UserControl.

I'd like to do this with as little code behind as possible.  The more data binding and XAML duct tape the better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use complex user controls in a `DataTemplate`; just declare the `DataTemplate` as your `UserControl`.

Example:

```
  <Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300" Name="UI" >
        <Window.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:House}" >
                <local:HouseUserControl DataContext="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Apartment}">
                 <local:ApartmentUserControl DataContext="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Window.Resources>

        <Grid>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=UI, Path=ListOfBuildings}" />
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Comment: Sweet!  Thats exactly what I need.  Didn't know you could bind to the type of the data source.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I see the problem. Just create DataTemplates for each type in your resources somewhere and WPF will use them automatically to render each type.

Comment: But I already have custom (highly complex) UserControls that have a fare amount of code behind.  So a DataTemplate doesn't really work for me.

Comment: So just declare templates that contain the appropriate UserControl?